# In Unity Asset store, is there no way to preview (hear) an individual wav file within a package of many audio clips

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, package, assets

In the 'Package Content' tab for an audio clip asset, the individual wav file names are listed. Clicking on a wav file name displays a wave form of the audio but does not play it. There a 479 wav files in the package, how do I listen to just one in order to decide whether I wish do acquire for my game? The package I am looking at has 479 audio clips, the only preview seems to be for the whole package which is impractical for previewing [image]just one clip.

Comment: As its a free package. Just download and try it.   If it was a paid one your problem would be more understandable

Comment: This one is free, but I am in interested in some paid content as well which also has this issue and would like to preview before buying. It seems incomprehensible that there is not a way to preview individual wav clips.

Comment: Id guess the fear is if it  lets you play it you can steal it.

Comment: I downloaded a free package and I can't even find a way to preview (hear) a wav file in the package manager 'import' window. I seem to have to import it before I can listen to it. Is there a way to at least preview after download but before import?